# Configure MapReduce program to run only reducer in existing program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, configure, reduce

Can a mapreduce program be configured such that only reducer is executed not mapper[even though there is a map function defined in the program]. Can this be achieved just by changing job configuration.

I want to implement incremental computation in mapreduce(with input as append only files). For example

For wordcount,

If wordcount is already executed on a file, after which some more data is appended to the input file.

If again wordcount is executed on the updated input file, I want to execute wordcount only on the new data and combine the old results with this. **For this combining of outputs I want to execute reducer alone separately**.

Comment: This entirely depends on what you are doing: are you joining data or do you want to reduce already sorted data?

Comment: I have updated the question on what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Hadoop requires you to do a `map`, while the `reduce` is optional.

If you want to do a group-by, you can try to use `Apache Tez` and configure a DAG that will the same what you want to archieve (might be still hacky, because you will need to use the internal data format).

Answer (score 0):

yes You can!, use this code as mapper(python_version)

`import sys
for i in sys.stdin:
   print i`

this will do the trick, because mapper is must one. so just print the contents of the input with a dummy mapper

I guess that helped!